# Finding the area inside a petal of a Rose Curve and outside the petal of another

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

[image]

This is the question I was given. I feel like it is supposed to be basic, but I am getting stuck. To me, it looks like if I find the area of half the red petal and subtract out the area of the part of the blue petal that is in the inside, I will get the correct answer. That gives me: $$\text{Area of half of red petal:}\frac12\int^{\frac{\pi}{6}}_04\cos^2(3\theta)\ d\theta \tag{1}$$$$\text{Area of section of blue petal:}\frac12\int^{\frac{\pi}{12}}_04\sin^2(3\theta)\ d\theta \tag2$$$$\text{Subtract second from first:}\frac12\int^{\frac{\pi}{6}}_04\cos^2(3\theta)\ d\theta -\frac12\int^{\frac{\pi}{12}}_04\sin^2(3\theta)\ d\theta \tag3$$

Is this setup correct?

Answer (score 1):

There is problem in your "Area section of blue petal".

Imagine line $\theta =\dfrac{\pi}{12}$(join origin radially to intersection point) .Now what you're doing is subtracting area bounded between **below** this line and **above yellow region** only. Thus leaving behind small area bounded between **above** this line and  below **red petal**.

correct set up should be

$$\text{required area }= \frac12\int^{\frac{\pi}{6}}_04\cos^2(3\theta)\ d\theta -\color{red} 2\times\frac12\int^{\frac{\pi}{12}}_04\sin^2(3\theta)\ d\theta $$

$=\dfrac{\pi}{6}-\dfrac{\pi-2}{6}=\dfrac{1}{3}$

Comment: I see - the way I did it only got half of the blue petal - so I need to double it